# Is it a way to find out all the IP address of an ELB without check the ELB config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, amazon-elb

When I ping the domain name of the ELB repeatedly, sometimes it show different IP addresses, and sometimes it just show one IP address. I don't have permissions to check the settings of the ELB. And I need to set up a firewall for all the possible IP address.

Is it a way to get all the IP address an ELB can forward?

Comment: The IP address of the Load Balancer will change as it scales to load, so you might need to find an alternate method. Can you tell us more about your requirements to configure the firewall? What are your security goals? How/where will the firewall filter traffic? Is it in the cloud or on-premises?

Comment: For example, if elb has 10.0.0.1, 10.0.1.2, 10.0.32.1, I will need add all these three addresses. Right now I try to keep pinging and hope it will get all addresses.

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to add those addresses? Where is your "firewall" located? What security goal is it trying to impose? Is it whitelisting inbound traffic? What actual _result_ are you wanting to achieve in terms of rules (as opposed to a specific configuration)?

Comment: it's a in house system and it's white list out bound list.  I cannot control it. What they need from me is to get all the addresses.

Comment: And I cannot use 10.0.0.0/16. I need to get the individual addresses.

Comment: And I cannot use 10.0.0.0/16. I need the full individual addresses. I kind of see someone use nc command to get them.

Comment: Might be relevant: [Using static IP addresses for Application Load Balancers | Networking & Content Delivery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/) and [2 ways to set up static IP addresses for ALB](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/static-ips-for-aws-application-load-balancer).

Comment: The elb is owned by another company, I have no control of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can front the ELB with a network loadbalancer (NLB) and access via the ip of the NLB.

Here's a blog post about it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/